# using lower_bound/upper_bound with 2 different types

Tags: c++

I have a small working code for finding a range of items that uses a special compare method. But when I try to rewrite it with `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` function, I get a strange error. I have written a small code to show my problem. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "banana";
    string keyword = "ana";
    int sa_idx[] = {5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2};
    vector<int> sa(sa_idx, sa_idx + sizeof(sa_idx) / sizeof(int) );

    auto cmp = [&str] (const int &a, const string &keyword) -> bool
    {
        return strncmp(str.c_str() + a,  keyword.c_str(), keyword.length()) < 0;
    };

    cout << (upper_bound(sa.begin(), sa.end(), keyword, cmp) - 
        lower_bound(sa.begin(), sa.end(), keyword, cmp)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you see, compare function uses keyword and value of `sa` array for compare decision. A [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) says:

> The type Type1 must be such that an object of type ForwardIt can be
>   dereferenced and then implicitly converted to Type1. The type Type2
>   must be such that an object of type T can be implicitly converted to
>   Type2.

My compare function has `int` type for first argument(because of `vector<int>` of array) and `string` for the second argument type(as type of keyword). But I don't know why I get following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Value&, _Iterator) [with _Value = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(const int&, const string&)>]’:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:2049:14:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__upper_bound(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const int&, const string&)> >]’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:2114:32:   required from ‘_FIter std::upper_bound(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Compare = main()::<lambda(const int&, const string&)>]’
prog.cpp:19:57:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/predefined_ops.h:173:11: error: no match for call to ‘(main()::<lambda(const int&, const string&)>) (const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, int&)’
  { return bool(_M_comp(__val, *__it)); }
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:14:61: note: candidate: main()::<lambda(const int&, const string&)>
  auto cmp = [&str] (const int &a, const string &keyword) -> bool
                                                             ^~~~
prog.cpp:14:61: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const int&’
```

Have I missed something super obvious? Because it seems compiler looks for `string` as first argument of compare function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem here is that `std::uppper_bound` requires the `cmp` be of the signature

```
bool(T, decltype(*Iterator))
```

`std::lower_bound` has the opposite requirement though and wants

```
bool(decltype(*Iterator), T)
```

so you can't use the same comparator with both functions.  There are other ways to modify the code but just adding a second comparator like

```
auto cmp1 = [&str](const string &keyword, const int &a) -> bool 
{ 
    return strncmp(keyword.c_str(), str.c_str() + a, keyword.length()) < 0;
};
auto cmp2 = [&str] (const int &a, const string &keyword) -> bool
{
    return strncmp(str.c_str() + a,  keyword.c_str(), keyword.length()) < 0;
};

cout << (upper_bound(sa.begin(), sa.end(), keyword, cmp1) - 
    lower_bound(sa.begin(), sa.end(), keyword, cmp2)) << endl;
```

allows the code to compile.

Comment: ouch...but WTH....I never thought that syntax of compare function will differ for `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`....

Comment: @Afshin Yeah, it is a bit weird that it does that.  I guess they do it because `upper_bound` checks if the value is less than the iterator while `lower_bound` checks if the iterator is less than the value so they have their signatures match that wording.